# undefined reference to Sigar library

Tags: c++, qt, cpu-usage, sigar

I'm writing a code to get the CPU Usage with the Sigar library but when i try to compile the code i get this error: undefined reference to `sigar_cpu_perc_calculate(sigar_cpu_t*, sigar_cpu_t*, sigar_cpu_perc_t*)@12'
What is wrong with my code? in the .pro file i added

```
INCLUDEPATH += "path_to\\sigar-bin\\include"
LIBS += "path_to\\sigar-bin\\lib\\sigar-x86-winnt.lib"
```

Code:

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <sigar.h>
#include <sigar_format.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    sigar_t *sigarcpu1;
    sigar_cpu_t cpu1;
    sigar_open(&sigarcpu1);
    sigar_cpu_get(sigarcpu1, &cpu1);
    sigar_close(sigarcpu1);

    sigar_t *sigarcpu2;
    sigar_cpu_t cpu2;
    sigar_open(&sigarcpu2);
    sigar_cpu_get(sigarcpu2, &cpu2);
    sigar_close(sigarcpu2);

    sigar_cpu_perc_t perc;
    sigar_cpu_perc_calculate(&cpu1, &cpu2, &perc);
    qDebug() << perc.combined;

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Maybe need to wrap the sigar includes in an `extern "C" {...}` block??

Comment: Ok now the code compiles, but i'm get "nan" of perc.combined result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

```
extern "C" {
#include <sigar_format.h>
}
```

See here:-

http://communities.vmware.com/thread/389369

Comment: The code compiles now, but i get "nan" of perc.combined result. Doing another question, how to get the cpu usage percent?